# String input validation for a letter followed by a number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want the userinput to be in the format letter number. The letters should
be from `A-H` and the numbers should be in between `1-7` For exampel `A4` or `H7`.
I don't want the the userinput to be for example `AA`,`AAA`,`2B` or `22`.
This is what I have done so far:

```
x=input("Write something:")

if len(x) !=2:
    print("Wrong")

letter=x[0]
number= x[1]

if number >=8:
    print("Wrong")

if letter not ["A","B","C","D","F","G"]:
    print("Wrong")

if letter == int:
    print("Wrong")

if number == str:
    print("Wrong")

else:
    print("Perfect")
```

Comment: What is the exact issue?

Comment: Why are you tagging this both as both Python 3 and Python 2? Pick one. Especially since the `input` function you're using works differently in them.

Comment: Why wouldn't this [A-H][1-7] work?

Comment: Hi! python 3 is the correct tag, sorry for that. Thank you,  [A-H][1-7] is a good way of doing it.

Answer (score 4):

I would do this with a [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) match:

```
import re

x=input("Write something: ")

if re.match('^[A-H][1-7]$',x):
     print('Perfect!')
else:
     print ('Wrong')
```

The regular expression `'^[A-H][1-7]$'` is the pattern the `x` must fit.

```
^      # This character matches the start of the string
[A-H]  # After the start of the string we allow the group A-H (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H)
[1-7]  # The next character must be a digit between 1 and 7
$      # This character matches the end of the string
```

The use of the anchors `^,$` means that the length of `x` must be 2, this is implicit so we don't need a separate check for this.

An improvement that loops until a correct value is received:

```
import re

while not re.match('^[A-H][1-7]$',input("Write something: ")):
     print('Wrong')

print('Perfect!')
```

Demo:

```
Write something: 11
Wrong
Write something: AA
Wrong
Write something: a1
Wrong
Write something: A9
Wrong
Write something: A1
Perfect!
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if letter == int:
    print("Wrong")

if number == str:
    print("Wrong")
```

This won't work for two reasons.  First, both letter and number are always technically strings in this case.  Any input from the keyboard is a string even if it's a digit.  And second, the `==` operator is for comparing the equality of two objects ("objects" here including strings or integers or even classes) and isn't the same thing as asking, "is this object an instance of this class".

I agree with the other answers in that you would be best served by a regex, but if you just want to use conditionals to tell if a string is a single-character digit or letter, you can do it using string methods:

```
if not letter.isalpha():
    print("Wrong")

if not number.isdigit():
    print("Wrong")
```

Comment: Thanks!, I agree with you @Andrew Gorcester

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect use case for regular expressions,

```
import re
x = input("Write something")
if re.match("^[A-H][1-7]$", x):
    print("Perfect")
```

Comment: This isn't strict enough for instance `A1junk` is a match. You need too anchor at start and end of the string.

Comment: Good point, @sudo_O - fixed my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Perfect scenario to use regular expression

```
import re
x=input("Write something: ")
print("Perfect" if re.match('^[A-H][1-7]$', x) else "Wrong")
```

Comment: hi, im a beginner, why do i need to import re? What is it?

Comment: @user1847307, `re` is the built-in Regular Expression module for python. Before you can use `re.match` it must be loaded into your current namespace.